# IdNumber: a string of fixed length and with character constraints

Tags: c#

In my program, I have special id numbers. They have a fixed length of 10 characters and may only contain digits and lowercase letter. I created my own data type for this. I want to be able to assign string values to it (with the `implicit` operator). When I do so, there should be automatically a verification if all conditions are met (the length and the constraints at the characters).

```
public class IdNumber
{
    private string idnumber;

    public static implicit operator IdNumber(string value)
    {
        if (value.Length == 10 && value.All(c => IsDigit(c) || IsLowercaseLetter(c)))
        {
            IdNumber m = new IdNumber();
            m.idnumber = value;
            return m;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("id numer must have length 10 and must only have digits and lower case-letters");
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return idnumber;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return idnumber.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if(obj is IdNumber other)
        {
            return this.idnumber == other.idnumber;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static bool operator ==(IdNumber m1, IdNumber m2)
    {
        if(m1 is null)
        {
            return m2 is null;
        }
        return m1.Equals(m2);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(IdNumber m1, IdNumber m2)
    {
        return !(m1 == m2);
    }

    private static bool IsDigit(char c)
    {
        return c >= '0' && c <= '9';
    }

    private static bool IsLowercaseLetter(char c)
    {
        return c >= 'a' && c <= 'z';
    }
}
```

Now I can use it via

```
IdNumber myId = "ab45jk23zz";
IdNumber otherId = "asfd" // throws exception
```

I have never used the implicit operator and I am also not sure about overriding the GetHashCode method (I want to use them as a key in a `Dictionary`, so it is important this works correctly). Hence I want to be sure I did not overlook anything. Of course, any other suggestions for improvement are welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will review your code from top to bottom.

```
private string idnumber;
```

this should be named using `camelCase` casing and because you don't change its value you should make it `readonly` which means you can only assign a value to it inside the constructor or by initialising like e.g `private string idnumber = "somevalue";`. Because you set this value only inside the `implicit` operator you should add a `private` constructor which has a `string` as argument. This would then look like this

```
public class IdNumber
{
    private readonly string idNumber;
    private IdNumber(string idNumber)
    {
        this.idNumber = idNumber;
    }
```

Because the `implicit` operator is `public` you should validate the argument `value` wether it is `null`. It just looks better to throw an `ArgumentNullException` than to receive an `NullReferenceException`.

Instead of using `value.All(c => IsDigit(c) || IsLowercaseLetter(c))` you could use a simple `Regex` to do the validation for you. This will shorten your code because the two methods `IsDigit()` and `IsLowercaseLetter()` won't be needed anymore.

The `implicit` operator would then look like this

```
public static implicit operator IdNumber(string value)
{
    if (value is null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value)); }

    if (Regex.IsMatch(value, "[0-9a-z]{10}"))
    {
        return new IdNumber(value);
    }
    throw new ArgumentException("id numer must have length 10 and must only have digits and lower case-letters");
}
```

`ToString()` and `GetHashCode()` are both fine but in the `Equals()` method you can either just remove the `else` like so

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if(obj is IdNumber other)
    {
        return this.idNumber == other.idNumber;
    }

    return false;
}
```

or combine the `if` condition with the idNumber comparision like so

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return (obj is IdNumber other) 
        && this.idNumber == other.idNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Along with what @Heslacher mentioned.

There are some areas also can be improved.

The `IsDigit` and `IsLowercaseLetter` methods can be improved, as you're not handling any exceptions inside them, 
while there is an existing `char.IsDigit` and `char.IsLower` extensions that can be used instead, which is better handled. 
I'm sure using the .NET built-in extensions would be better option than recreating your own.

Another important point is that you're validating the input implicitly only! So, you either will have to copy & paste same condition on the constructor or any new method that will take an input to convert it to `IdNumber` or you'll stick with the implicit operator as a way of conversion. Both are not good practice.

What you want to do is to create a method to validate the input, which will help you to reuse it whenever needed.

example:

```
// Validate Id
public bool IsValid(string idNumber)
{
    return
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(idNumber) ? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(idNumber))
      : idNumber.Length == 10 && idNumber.All(x => char.IsDigit(x) || char.IsLower(x));
}
```

if the string is empty or null will throw `ArgumentNullException` otherwise will validate the input then return either true or false. you can see I used `char.IsDigit(x)` and `char.IsLower(x)` and that's because it has more validations at the back-scene, but most importantly, it checks the character Unicode which is important in your case as you always need a Numeric & a lower-case Latin (English) Letter which it's already covered in them.

With this method, you're eliminating the need of `IsLowercaseLetter(char c)` && `IsDigit(char c)` custom methods.

Now, you'll need to design your constructor first, before even thinking of your implicit operators (these can be saved for last).

we can define two constructors:

```
// store Id as string
private readonly string _idNumber;

// Auto Generate new id from Guid (just an example).
public IdNumber()
{
    _idNumber = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "").Substring(0, 10).ToLower();
}

// Initiate the Id from the constructor.                
public IdNumber(string idNumber)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(idNumber)) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(idNumber)); }

    if (IsValid(idNumber))
    {
        _idNumber = idNumber;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("id numer must have length 10 and must only have digits and lower case-letters");
    }
}
```

You added the ability to initiate a new Id via the constructors, either an auto generated Id, or a specific one, these two constructors will come in handy.

The `ToString()` should have null check, why ? it's a procedure were you expect the unexpected. (welcome to my world ;) ).

```
// Override the ToString(), and validate the string with string.IsNullOrEmpty()
public override string ToString() => string.IsNullOrEmpty(_idNumber) ? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(_idNumber)) : _idNumber;
```

Now, the equality operations in `Equals()` and `==` and also `!=` in your code are treated the same (you're compare between objects values). Because of that, you can make `Equals()` main method of equality check, then just recall it in your other operators.

```
// Include conditions to cover null and string objects and use switch statement for better readability. (also easier to extend).
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
        switch (obj)
        {
            case IdNumber other:
                return _idNumber == other._idNumber;
            case string other: 
                return string.IsNullOrEmpty(other) ? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(other)) : _idNumber == other;
            case null:
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(obj));
            default:
                return false;
        }

}

// Call Equals()
public static bool operator ==(IdNumber m1, IdNumber m2) => m1.Equals(m2);

// Call Equals()
public static bool operator !=(IdNumber m1, IdNumber m2) => !m1.Equals(m2);
```

For the implicit operator, since we have already implemented our constructors and validation,(i told you it'll come in handy)  we can do this:

```
// Cast string to IdNumber
public static implicit operator IdNumber(string value) => new IdNumber(value);
```

now, we can also add another implicit operator to do the reverse casting (from IdNumber to string), so we don't need to call `ToString()`

```
public static implicit operator string(IdNumber value) => value.ToString();
```

now you can cast back and forth between string and IdNumber directly.

we can now test them out :

```
// test 1 : initiate IdNumber with a string (without using the constructor)
IdNumber id = "ab45jk23zz";

// test 2 : Initiate a new IdNumber via constructor
var id2 = new IdNumber("ab45jk23zz");

// test 3 : Initiate a new random IdNumber
var id3 = new IdNumber();

// test 4 : convert IdNumber ToString()
var test = id.ToString();

// test 5 : cast IdNumber to string
var test2 = (string)id;

// test 6 : cast string to IdNumber
var test3 = (IdNumber)test;

// Between IdNumber objects 
var equalityTest = id.Equals(id2);

// Between IdNumber objects 
var equalityTest2 = id == id2;

// Between IdNumber & string 
var equalityTest3 = id.Equals("ab45jk23zz");

// Between IdNumber & string
var equalityTest4 = id == "ab45jk23zz";
```

Comment: a string is an IEnumerable<char>, so this ToCharArray is not necessary.

Comment: @Holger thanks for mention that, I didn't noticed it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. I have a question about overloading the == and != operators: When I do `null == someIdNumber`, this will throw a NullReferenceException because `m1` will be null, won't it?

Comment: @SomeBody yes, you'll have to handle `m1 && m2` nullity, or you can adjust it to `m1 is null || m2 is null ? false : m1.Equals(m2);` this way you'll get false when you compare it with nulls, and it won't throw NullReferenceException.